# Get the missing numbers for each section

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the missing protocol Numbers from this list for each section 
I have my list

```
    ProtocolNumber  Section
--------------------------------
    14A1000014  |     A1
    14A1000015  |     A1
    14A1000018  |     A1
    14A1000019  |     A1
    14A2000014  |     A2
    14A2000015  |     A2
    14A2000019  |     A2
```

I try this

```
SELECT  lb1.ProtocolNumber, lb1.Section  FROM #tmp lb1 
        WHERE not exists ( SELECT * FROM #tmp lb2
                       WHERE lb2.ProtocolNumber = lb1.ProtocolNumber + 1  and lb2.Section = lb1.Section)
```

The output should be like this

```
   ProtocolNumber   Section
--------------------------------
    14A1000016  |     A1
    14A1000017  |     A1
    14A2000016  |     A2
    14A2000017  |     A2
    14A2000018  |     A2
```

Comment: can you offer an expected output?

Comment: What defines a "Missing Number"?  If you're wanting to check all of the values within a range of possible values, what defines that range?

Comment: I think my code is wrong

Comment: @New_World, can you provide a bit of detail around the `ProtocolNumber` field?  Does it always equal `14` + `Section` + 6-digit number?  What defines the start / end range of the 6-digit numbers?

Comment: @AHiggins yes always 14 + section + 6 digit number

Comment: And what 6-digit numbers are valid?  Because there are a million of them.  Literally.

Comment: In order to identify what is missing you need to know what must exist.  Is there a master list of Protocol numbers that you can join back to?  Or would you have to create a list of required protocol numbers?  eg. Do a left outer join from your master Protocol list to your temp table where temp table value is not null

Comment: no it just this numbers I have only this list in my table

Comment: I think your problem is with lb2.ProtocolNumber = lb1.ProtocolNumber + 1 because you can't add 1 to a string.  You want to add 1 to the numeric portion of the string and compare it to the numeric portion of the other row.  The other problem with your approach, however, is that it will only test for the next value after an existing one, so 16 should be returned, as 15 exists, but not 17 or 18.  Also, wouldn't it always return the max# + 1 for each section? (#20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assumption that you are trying to generate a list of missing protocol numbers between the minimum and maximum range currently existing for that section, I'd suggest the following:

```
/*Sample Data*/
CREATE TABLE #tmp (ProtocolNumber VARCHAR(20), Section VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO #tmp (ProtocolNumber, Section) SELECT'14A1000014',      'A1' 
INSERT INTO #tmp (ProtocolNumber, Section) SELECT'14A1000015',      'A1'
INSERT INTO #tmp (ProtocolNumber, Section) SELECT'14A1000018',      'A1'
INSERT INTO #tmp (ProtocolNumber, Section) SELECT'14A1000019',      'A1'
INSERT INTO #tmp (ProtocolNumber, Section) SELECT'14A2000014',      'A2'
INSERT INTO #tmp (ProtocolNumber, Section) SELECT'14A2000015',      'A2'
INSERT INTO #tmp (ProtocolNumber, Section) SELECT'14A2000019',      'A2'

/*CTEs to generate numbers list: 1 through 1,000,000*/
;WITH 
    E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) s(N)), 
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows 
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max 
    E5(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b), --1,000,000 rows max 
    cteTally(N) AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E5 ),
/*CTE to identify ranges of current numbers for each Section*/
    Ranges AS 
      (
        SELECT 
            Section, 
            MIN(CAST(SUBSTRING(ProtocolNumber, 5,6) AS INT)) MinNumber, 
            MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ProtocolNumber, 5,6) AS INT)) MaxNumber
        FROM 
            #tmp 
        GROUP BY Section 
      ),
/*CTE to generate full list of available protocols for each Section*/
    ProtocolList AS 
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            Section,
            '14' + Section + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(N AS VARCHAR(6)),6) AS ProtocolNumber
        FROM Ranges 
         INNER JOIN 
        cteTally ON 
            cteTally.N >= Ranges.MinNumber AND 
            cteTally.N <= Ranges.MaxNumber

      )

/*Final SELECT - protocols in the master list that do not exist for those sections in the temp table*/

SELECT l.ProtocolNumber, l.Section
FROM 
    ProtocolList l
     LEFT JOIN 
    #tmp t ON 
        l.ProtocolNumber = t.ProtocolNumber
WHERE t.ProtocolNumber IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    l.Section, 
    l.ProtocolNumber

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: I think you can drop the = when comparing cteTally and Ranges min/max.  you could also exclude rows unless max-min>2.

Comment: @Beth, I believe you are correct!  I usually come at problems like this trying to get all possibles and whatever matches exist, but since the OP is asking to only see missing, the `=` sign is superfluous.  That said, though, I'll leave it the way it is, both for simplicity's sake and in case requirements ever shift to cover that scenario.  Thanks for pointing that out, though!

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a one line select statment?

How about writing a stored procedure or Table-Valued function that using cursor iterates through your table and creates missing records, which the function returns

Implemenation would also need to check for max protocol number for each give section so that you only create records with in range

Comment: can u provide me exemple please

Answer (score 0):

LIST OF MISSING PROTOCOL

```
 DECLARE @P INT=(SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT SECTION) FROM PROTOCOL) --NUMBER OF SECTION
DECLARE @w varchar(10)='A1'   --HOLD TYPE OF SECTION
WHILE @P>0
BEGIN
DECLARE @q table(numx int)  --HOLD MAX TO MIN ProtocolNumber
declare @i table(num int)   --HOLD EXISTS 'ProtocolNumber'
INSERT INTO @i
select  convert(int,right( ProtocolNumber,2)) FROM protocol  WHERE Section=@w
DECLARE @x int=(select max(convert(int,right( ProtocolNumber,2))) FROM protocol WHERE Section=@w)
DECLARE @y int=(select min(convert(int,right( ProtocolNumber,2))) FROM protocol WHERE Section=@w)
 WHILE @y <= @x  
begin
INSERT INTO @q (numx)
VALUES(@y)
SET @y= @y + 1
END
SELECT ('14'+@w+'0000'+ convert(varchar(10),numx)) AS ProtocolNumber,@W AS Section
FROM  @Q
 where  numx NOT IN (select  * FROM @i)
  SET @P=@P-1
 SET @W='A2'
 DELETE FROM @Q
 DELETE  FROM @I
 END
```

[image]

Comment: REPLACE 'PROTOCOL' WITH YOUR TABLE NAME.